# Python twitter library for public api

Tags: python, twitter, public, timeline

i am looking for a python library that works with twitter api v1.1 .I want to extract public tweets. But the public timeline method has been deprecated in the newer version, so this does not work in older python implementation.Please suggest new libraries of python that can help me do so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the  https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/'s library method:

```
  >>> statuses = api.GetPublicTimeline()
  >>> print [s.user.name for s in statuses]
  [u'DeWitt', u'Kesuke Miyagi', u'ev', u'Buzz Andersen', u'Biz Stone']
```